# AutoScriptWriter Macro not working

Tags: autohotkey

I created a little macro that was all mouse clicks with AutoScriptWriter that worked well immediately after I had created it, but later when I opened the program it was working in and started the macro, it showed up in my system tray, but nothing happened. I hadn't yet assigned a hotkey and was just clicking on macro to run it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ellen

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

run C:\Program Files\VinylStudio\VinylStudio.exe, , max

#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;  Allow more flexibility in matching the windows title.
SetTimer, CloseScript, 1000
Return ; stop the script here on startup

CloseScript:
IfWinExist ahk_class VinylStudio_main
    Return
ExitApp

#ifWinActive ahk_class VinylStudio_main

^h:: ; Here I assigned the hotkey [Ctrl]+h

WinActivate, VinylStudio
WinWait, VinylStudio, , 3 ; Wait for 3 seconds and then alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, VinylStudio timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  479,  79 ; MouseClicks are less reliable than keyboard shortcuts or ControlSend/ControlClick.
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  421,  40
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  425,  443
Sleep, 100
WinWait, Filter Settings, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Filter Settings timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  29,  109
Sleep, 100
WinWait, Define Noise Sample, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Define Noise Sample timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  388,  168
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left, -86,  660, 2
;MouseClick, left, -86,  660
Sleep, 100
WinWait, VinylStudio, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, VinylStudio timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  200,  675, 2
;MouseClick, left,  200,  675
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  200,  675, 2
;MouseClick, left,  200,  675
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  201,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  203,  673, 2
;MouseClick, left,  203,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  203,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  787,  645
Sleep, 100
Return


#ifwinactive
```

Comment: Ellen, Your question is very vague. Would you be able to cut/paste the code you are using in the question? After you pasted the code, highlight the code and press [Ctrl]+k to format it as a code block.

Comment: Here it is (and thanks for explaining how to set as code):

Comment: Ellen, So far I have not seen the code (despite your message "Here it is")? You know that you can edit the original question and just ADD your code there.

Comment: I didn't realize I could only add it to my original post.

Comment: According to my understanding, AutoScriptWriter is a tool, that lets you record your input in order to reproduce it automatically when needed. This may work well in simple cases, where there's just a few keys to send. But the more complex your process becomes, the less reliable such macro recorders get. Do you know how to actually program with AHK? In my experience, you are always better off scripting things yourself, as there are many circumstances, macro recorders just can't infer and therefore fail to reproduce.

Comment: Ellen, I saw that you changed the hotkey to [Ctrl]+h, but you left the comment saying that the hotkey is [Alt]+v. All in all I must say that you created an impressive script for, as you call yourself: "a beginner".

Comment: Robert, Oops . . . fixed that. Thanks for the encouragement; I couldn't have done it without your help -- quite literally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I looked at it. In the current code you do check a lot, but never know where your checks fail.

Here is a start with some cleaned up code:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;  Allow more flexibility in matching the windows title.
Return ; stop the script here on startup

!v:: ; Here I assigned the hotkey [Alt]+v
;IfWinNotExist, VinylStudio ; Line could be removed if VS is running
;    Run, VinylStudio.exe Collection.mcf ; Line could be removed
WinActivate, VinylStudio
WinWait, VinylStudio, , 3 ; Wait for 3 seconds and then alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, VinylStudio timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  479,  79 ; MouseClicks are less reliable than keyboard shortcuts or ControlSend/ControlClick.
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  421,  40
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  425,  443
Sleep, 100
WinWait, Filter Settings, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Filter Settings timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  29,  109
Sleep, 100
WinWait, Define Noise Sample, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Define Noise Sample timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  388,  168
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left, -86,  660, 2
;MouseClick, left, -86,  660
Sleep, 100
WinWait, VinylStudio, , 3 ; Wait 3 seconds for pop-up else alert user
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, VinylStudio timed out.
    return
}
MouseClick, left,  200,  675, 2
;MouseClick, left,  200,  675
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  200,  675, 2
;MouseClick, left,  200,  675
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  201,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  203,  673, 2
;MouseClick, left,  203,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  203,  673
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  787,  645
Sleep, 100
Return
```

Ellen, Try to avoid clicking on coordinates. A better way is to e.g. use ControlSend or ControlClick and send the information/click to a specific object. You can often find the object name with the AHK Windows Spy (under classNN). A ControlClick could look like: ControlClick, Toolbar321, VinylStudio  or ControlClick, OK, Define Noise Sample  to click on the OK button in the "Define Noise Sample" window.

I assigned a hotkey [Alt]+v, but you can create any combination you like.
! =<kbd>Alt</kbd>,
^ =<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,
 # =<kbd>Win</kbd>,
+ =<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

So
!t = <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,
^+F2 =<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and
 #w =<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

After the hotkey I still check to see if VS is running and if not I start it, but you can remove those lines and place your hotkey just above WinActivate, VinylStudio

Comment: Robert, Thank you, that works. I trimmed the tray tip & beep. What I want is to assign it a hotkey and run it when VS is open. How do I assign a hotkey to run the script? My attempts have been unsuccessful.

I am close to a complete beginner, and writing a script  like this by hand is beyond me at this point. With limited time & energy to devote to this now, I find the online instructional information sometimes confusing. I wish  there were a comprehensive manual. 

I compared your script with the old one and I wish I'd understood why the changes you made make it work.

Comment: Ellen, I'm surprised that the code worked immediately, since I had no way of testing it and just had to imagine what was happening. I added a hotkey ([Alt]+v) but you can change that. If the script now hangs because of a window title mismatch, you will get a message, so you know where to look for the solution. Once you're happy, could you check my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Robert, Yes, thanks very much , that works. 

I've got it opening VS, and closing with the program, based on previous code you helped me with (see edited version), so I'm learning. :)

If it's not too much trouble, could you explain what you fixed in the original code, so hopefully the next time I record a similar type of macro, I can get it to work? Also, is there a quick way to select all the code in a gray box to copy it?

Comment: Ellen, the main thing I did was to define: SetTitleMatchMode, 2  This way you don't need to match the EXACT window title string, but you can use a unique portion out of the window title. The other thing I did was to reduce the number of WinWait and WinActivate, but where I used them I made sure that if the window with the right title could not be found, you will get an alert message, so you can better troubleshoot. And copying the code??? Maybe there is a better way, but I just highlight the first line and then use the scrollwheel to highlight it all the way.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I will try to apply that to the next recorded macro.